# Javascript doesn't work after website transfer

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have some issue with javascript after website transfer. All others scripts works fine but not this one

On demo version it works fine, but on live it do nothing and its giving 0 errors.

```js
var vienasloop = true;
if (vienasloop) {
  if (window.location.hash) {
    $('li').on('click', function() { //here

      first = $(this).siblings().eq(0).detach();
      $(this).parent().prepend($(this).after(first).detach());
    });

    if (window.location.hash != "") {
      $('li').eq(Number(window.location.hash.slice(1)) + 2).click();
    }
  }
}
$('body').html(String($('body').html()).replace("var vienasloop = true;",
  "var vienasloop = false;"));
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32445/)

Comment: That's incomplete code... is `window.location.hash` true?

Comment: Any error in console? Also can you past the corresponding HTML on which this is applied. So that we can check. Best would be either create a fiddle with your HTML and current code or gave you website link to check

Comment: this is all code of document : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32445/)

Comment: Console error  - there is a } too many after the `"var vienasloop = false;"));
} <<<<<` - possibly you want to move the `$('body').html.....` inside one of the ifs, but then there is STILL one } too many. Also what is this supposed to do `$('body').html(String($('body').html()).replace("var vienasloop = true;",
  "var vienasloop = false;"));` It is not going to affect the page in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because in your code, the `one` property doesn't exist, try something like this :

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    $('li').on('click' , function() { //here

        first = $(this).siblings().eq(0).detach();
        $(this).parent().prepend($(this).after(first).detach());
    });

    if (window.location.hash != "") {
        $('li').eq(Number(window.location.hash.slice(1)) + 2 ).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that `$.one` is a valid jquery method. Please have a look at its documentation at http://api.jquery.com/one/